# exponential moving sum in numpy / scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I am looking for a function to calculate exponential moving sum in numpy or scipy. I want to avoid using python loops because they are really slow.

to be specific, I have two series A[] and T[]. T[i] is the timestamp of value A[i]. I define a half-decay period tau. For a given time t, the exponential moving sum is the sum of all the values A[i] that happens before t, with weight exp(-(t-T[i])/tau) for each A[i].

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/contents.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [numpy.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html). The exponential moving sum is a convolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to improve python loops by doing good "practices" (like avoiding dots).

Maybe you can code you function in C (into a "numpy library") and call it from python.